# How to create a fieldset in a node form, that expands with ajax

Tags: views, ajax

I have a (view of a ) tasks list on a page, and also a form block where users can add a new tasks.
I want to increase page load time by hiding some fields in the tasks form block, which can expand using ajax by clicking on "task details" link (the fieldset label)

Is this is possible without programming?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without programming.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add this module.  https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group
Add those fields on the form to a field group, and set the group to start out "Collapsed".